# how to send a HTTP SEARCH request in HttpURLConnection on Android?

Tags: android, search, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I want to know if it is possible to send SEARCH request (practically) through java.net.HttpURLConnection to HTTP-based URL.

I have read so many articles describing that how to send GET, POST, DELETE requests but I still haven't found any sample code which successfully performs SEARCH request.

here is sample code.

```
public static String HTTPSearch(String urlAddress, String... searchDataPair) {
    HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 30000);

    DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
    ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();

    HttpSearch searchMethod = new HttpSearch (urlAddress);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
            putDataPair.length / 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < putDataPair.length; i += 2) {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(searchDataPair[i],
                searchDataPair[i + 1]));
    }

    String response = "";
    try {
        searchMethod .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = hc.execute(searchMethod , res);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

in this code, HttpSearch is error.
please help me about HttpSearch.

Comment: ` have read so many articles describing that how to send GET, POST, DELETE` do you use restful webservice?

Comment: I am working with active web service, but web service need search request method for some connection with client(android mobile). so I want to know about SEARCH request method of HTTPURLConnection.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by `active`?

Comment: sorry. I use restful web service based on JSON method.

Answer (score 0):

First, i dont know whether my approach is best or not.

Im using `restful codeigniter webservice`. What i did to implement `search` is by using `POST`. I simply POST the **search keyword** and then my `webservice` will perform `SQL Query` to search that `String` (keyword) im my database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I want to know sample code for SEARCH method of HTTPURLConnection on android.
IF you have ever done similar to the project, please let me know your request code on android. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), the setRequestMethod() does not allow for the SEARCH method (which makes sense, since from what I can tell SEARCH is [MS only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa143053%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx).  However, you can always try to use setRequestMethod() and see what happens.

Comment: SEARCH is not MS only. It is currently part of WebDAV and is a proposed standard for adding the SEARCH method as a way to request queries with complex criteria. The query parameters are passed through the body of the request.